# Updating prop value in child component when parent property updates Vue 3

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I'm having troubles to update the value of a prop in a child component, the documentation says "when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child" but that is not happening, i've made a summary of the code:

Parent's:

```
<script setup>
  import Child from "../components/Child.vue"
  
  var counter = 0

  setInterval(() => {
    counter++
    console.log(counter)
  }, 2000)

</script>

<template>
    <Child :counter="counter"/>
</template>
```

Child's:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue"

    const props = defineProps(['counter'])

    const count = ref(props.counter)
</script>

<template>
    <h1>{{ count }}</h1>
</template>
```

Anyone knows what could be wrong? I already tried to pass a ref object to the child and to put a watch function on the prop but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antwort from Gaetan C. is right, but not enough.

The counter data property is not reactive and changing it will not trigger updates.

```
var counter = 0;
```

should be

```
const counter = ref(0);
```

and then

```
counter.value++;
```

### Here is the playground

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const Child = {
  props: ['counter'],
  template: '<h1>{{ counter }}</h1>'
}

const App = {
  components: { 
    Child
  },
  setup() {    
    const counter = ref(0);
    
    setInterval(() => {
      counter.value++
    }, 2000)
    
    return { counter }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">  
    <child :counter="counter"></child>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```